Getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null" while trying to install NextJS
I'm following this official tutorial:
https://nextjs.org/learn/react-foundations/installation
When I run this command:
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest next@latest

I got this error:
npm error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')

The result in package.json file is:
{}

The latest error in the log is:
15063 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')
15063 verbose stack     at Link.matches (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/node.js:1115:41)
15063 verbose stack     at Link.canDedupe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/node.js:1069:15)
15063 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.pruneDedupable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:426:14)
15063 verbose stack     at new PlaceDep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:278:14)
15063 verbose stack     at #buildDepStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:939:18)
15063 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:203:7)
15063 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
15063 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:131:5)
15063 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:150:5)
15063 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli/entry.js:74:5)
15064 verbose cwd /Users/bcarneiro/MyProjects/nextjs-dashboard
15065 verbose Darwin 23.4.0
15066 verbose node v20.15.0
15067 verbose npm  v10.7.0
15068 error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')
15069 verbose exit 1
15070 verbose code 1

I'm new to frontend development and I have no idea how to debug and fix it.
The full log is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YUnLYuhjceuA2Eh0eGtNDvRqgjzUCAna/view?usp=sharing

you can publish everything you have in package.json

@CarlosTerrazas everything I have in package.json is already in the question. It is a empty object {}

I tried same thing in Ubuntu 22, with Same node and npm versions but can't replicate the issue. It works fine on my machine, I am using nvm for Node installations. From your logs it seems like we have an issue with NPM internally at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/node.js:1115 in line 1115. Examining the code in that file, it looks like we are checking something related to URL. Overall the issue doesn't seem with your code.

1: Please run both commands separately and ensure Node.js and npm are Installed Correctly:
 node -v
//Example result: v20.15.0

 npm -v
//Example result: 10.7.0

2: If you are setting up a Nextjs project from scratch, follow the official Next.js documentation.
According to the docs, you can run the following command to create a new Next.js app:
npx create-next-app@latest my-next-app

This should help you set up your Next.js application without any issues.

Hello Amit, the versions are already in the question. Node v20.15.0, npm  v10.7.0. I'm already following this official tutorial https://nextjs.org/learn/react-foundations/installation.

Hey Bruno, Are you doing a manual installation? what OS you are using ( windows/linux )? and running npx create-next-app@latest my-next-app also resulted in the same output? please let me know if this also gives an error.

you can install npm alternatives like yarn and bun then try with either.
